# Generator for Engine in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I created a mountable Engine in Rails 4.
I am testing it with a dummy test application.

I created my install generator in

'lib/myenginename/install/install_generator.rb':

```
require 'rails/generators/active_record'
require 'rails/generators/migration'

module Myengine
  module Generators
    class MyengineGenerator < Rails::Generators::Base

      desc "Installs mygem and generates the necessary migrations"
      source_root File.expand_path("../templates", __FILE__)

      def create_migrations
        migration_template 'migrations/m1.rb', 'db/migrate/m1.rb'
      end

    end
  end
end
```

But when I run

```
rails g myengine:install
```

it shows error:

```
Could not find generator 'myengine:install'. Maybe you meant ...
```

How to make generator for engine work?

Answer (score 1):

generator should be placed in file

```
lib/generators/myenginename/install_generator.rb
```

Answer (score 0):

The generator should be in `lib/generators/myenginename/`. Read up on http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/generators.html#creating-generators-with-generators